# JQuery timepicker on same line as ordered list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a website and ran into a snag. I am using a [timepicker](http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/) and I'm designing an ordered list which contains this sort of functionality. This is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dczz35k/1/). Here is my code:

```
    <!-- FAQ Nav -->
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="widget-container fluid-height">
            <div class="heading">
                <h2 id="bowl_info_start">Please select a bowl on your left to populate this field</h2>
                <p id="bowl_name"></p>
            </div>
            <div id="itinerary_main" class="widget-content padded">
            <!-- content of the itinerary -->
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
                        <input class="form-control" id="timepicker-default" type="text"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span></input>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                        <li>Tea</li>
                        <li>Milk</li>
                    </ol>               
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is something like this:

[image]

But what I get is this:

[image]

I want the timepicker to be on the same line as the ordered list item. Then I was going to make an un-ordered sub-list within that.

My main trouble is getting the timepicker to be on the same line as the ordered list item. I've tried tweaking the css but can't figure out whats going wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So adding "float: right" to .input-group.bootstrap-timepicker seems to give the results you were looking for.

```css
.input-group.bootstrap-timepicker {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- DataTables -->
<div class="row">
    <!-- FAQ Nav -->
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="widget-container fluid-height">
            <div class="heading">
                    <h2 id="bowl_info_start">Please select a bowl on your left to populate this field</h2>

                <p id="bowl_name"></p>
            </div>
            <div id="itinerary_main" class="widget-content padded">
                <!-- content of the itinerary -->
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
                            <input class="form-control" id="timepicker-default" type="text"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
                            </input>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>Tea</li>
                    <li>Milk</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could also change

```
.input-group.bootstrap-timepicker {
    float: right;
}
```

to

```
.input-group.bootstrap-timepicker {
    display: inline-table;
}
```

Comment: Thats perfect! Thank you.